# Wordpress new post default settings

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a blog in which I share posts. When creating the post I go through all of the metadata and settings to customize the post how I like it. Is there a way I can make my customizations to be the default settings for a new post so that I don't have to repeat this process every time.

My customizations are:

- Show Page Title = OFF
- Show Breadcrumb = OFF
- Category = news
- Tags = must not be empty
- Featured image = must not be empty
- Excerpt = must not be empty
- Don't start with blank post -> add default template from VisualComposer's templates ( mine is called DefaultPostTemplate )

Is there a way to have all of this things set up when I press "Add New Post" ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the action `save_post`, it's not totally what you want but i don't know any hook called at the init of a new post.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/save_post

Comment: This can work - it can change the "Show Page Title" and "Show Breadcrumb" to false, set the category to 'news' and even check if 'tags' and 'Featured Image' are empty. But how to produce an error if tags or featured image are empty ?

Comment: I found out how to have default template :)

Comment: I think this post should help you to "throw" error : http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/5102/add-validation-and-error-handling-when-saving-custom-fields